# 80's cartoon featuring a "magic toolbox"

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

This was so long ago I barely remember any of it- what I do recall is when the hero and his friends got in trouble, there would be this scene where (I think) the boy's arm would temporarily stretch (and possibly briefly change colour), then he would reach into his toolbox and retrieve the necessary device to help them out. Depending on the situation said tool might be a screwdriver, a wrench or a pair of pliers.

Comment: Reach into a literal box of tool? Or did the arm transform into the tool?

Comment: Teaching you how to suck eggs, but this question would be greatly improved by going through the checklists at [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: Was it definitely a cartoon and not e.g. a puppet show? Gerry Anderson's "Twizzle" was about a boy with extending limbs,

Comment: Was definitely a cartoon, and yes he reached into a literal toolbox. @Valorum- was a western style animation, not anime.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be Felix the Cat? The theme song for the 1950s TV animation went

```
  Felix the cat
  The wonderful, wonderful cat
  Whenever he gets in a fix
  He reaches into his bag of tricks
```

and that just about describes every episode of the cartoon.  The character was from an earlier print cartoon, but the bag of tricks gimmick was introduced by the TV version.

Comment: No, the kid and his friends were human, and it wasn't an "animals-acting-as-people" cartoon.